# Control variable within querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two images and would like both to log another text. How can I control which element is used within querySelectorAll?

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.penguin').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('Stackoverflow');
    });
});
```

```css
.penguin {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img class="penguin" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/NewTux.svg/1707px-NewTux.svg.png">
<img class="penguin" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/NewTux.svg/1707px-NewTux.svg.png">
```

I thought about using `elem[0]` but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by control which element is used? You can use `querySelector()` to just select the first one.

Comment: @Barmar so the first image should log for example `Stackoverflow` and the second one `Hello World`. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Say that in the question. It's not "controlling" anything, it's just taking different action depending on which was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use data attribute for different text values:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.penguin').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.target.dataset.text));
});
```

```css
.penguin {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img class="penguin" data-text="Stackoverflow 1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/NewTux.svg/1707px-NewTux.svg.png">
<img class="penguin" data-text="Stackoverflow 2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/NewTux.svg/1707px-NewTux.svg.png">
```